# Terraform error Error: Unsupported attribute when retrieving secret_id in azure

Tags: terraform

I am new to terraform and learning as i go along, today I have attempted to lay my hands on modules and to better understand how they work. To do this,I created a tf code to create a keyvault and my next challenge was to structure it as a module so that when creating loads of infrastructure, I don't end up with a massive main.tf file. So what have i got ?

I created a folder called create_kv_m10

inside that folder, you have the following.

**

- main_parent.tf

**

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
variable "subscription_id" {
}
variable "client_id" {
}
variable "tenant_id" {
}
variable "client_secret" {
}

module "create_kv" {
  source = "./modules/kv"
  secret_name = "test123"
  keyvault_name = "ra-infrastructure-kv"
  subscription_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id
  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  client_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id
  client_secret = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_secret
}
```

**

- providers.tf

**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
}
```

**

- terraform.tfvars

**

```
subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
tenant_id       = "cccccccccccccccccccccc"
keyvault_name   = "aac-learning-kv"
secret_name     = "resource-password"
secret_value    = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Now under the folder create_kv_m10, I have a subfolder called modules and under modules another folder called kv

**inside the kv folder I have the following files**

**

- create_kv.tf

**

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_gp" {
  name     = "terraform_learning"
  location = "UK South"

  tags = {
    "owner"   = "Me"
    "purpose" = "Practice terraform"
  }
}


variable "prefix" {
  default = "tf_dev"
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault" "testBuild_kv" {
  name                        = var.keyvault_name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  purge_protection_enabled    = true
  sku_name                    = "standard"

  access_policy = [{
    application_id              = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id
    enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
    certificate_permissions     = ["Get"]
    object_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
    storage_permissions         = ["Get"]
    tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

    key_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "Create",
      "Delete"
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Set",
      "Delete"
    ]
    storage_permissions = [
      "Get"
    ]

  }]


}



# resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "testBuild_kvuserpol" {
#   key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.testBuild_kv.id

#   tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
#   object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
# }


# resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "testBuild_kvkey" {
#   name         = "des-testBuild-key"
#   key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.testBuild_kv.id
#   key_type     = "RSA"
#   key_size     = 2048

#   depends_on = [
#     azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.testBuild_kvuserpol
#   ]

#   key_opts = [
#     "decrypt",
#     "encrypt",
#     "sign",
#     "unwrapKey",
#     "verify",
#     "wrapKey",
#   ]
# }


# resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "generic-resource-password" {

#   name = var.secret_name
#   value = var.secret_value
#   key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.testBuild_kv.id
# }
```

**

- terraform.tfvars

**

```
subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
tenant_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
keyvault_name   = "ty-learning-kv"
```

**

**- variables.tf**

**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
}

variable "subscription_id" {
  description = "Enter the Subscription ID for provisioning resources in Azure"
}

variable "client_id" {
  description = "Enter the Client ID for provisioning resources in Azure"

}

variable "client_secret" {
  description = "Enter the Client Secret for provisioning resources in Azure"

}

variable "tenant_id" {
  description = "Enter the Tenant ID for provisioning resources in Azure"

}

variable "keyvault_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Key vault name in Azure"
}

variable "secret_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Key vault name to be stored"
}

# variable "secret_value" {
#   type        = string
#   description = "Key vault name to be stored"
#   sensitive   = true
# }

variable "location" {
  type = string
  description = "The location of the resource"
  default = "UK South"
}
```

The issue I am having is that I get the error message as is

`Error: Unsupported attribute │ │   on main_parent.tf line 18, in module "create_kv": │   18:   client_secret = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_secret │ │ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "client_secret".`

If I however hardcode the value of `secret_id`, then it works or use `vars.secret_id`.

I am keen to understand why `data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_secret` doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't access `secret` without passing one. But, here the problem is not that. If you look at documentation of [azurerm_client_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/client_config), there is no attribute named `client_secret`. Your code assumed that something like that existed & you referenced it via `client_secret = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_secret`. That's why you have this error.

There are multiple ways of passing secrets to terraform `azurerm` provider. All of them are listed [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs).

The most preferred one is injecting secrets via env vars `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET` or if you have `az login` context, you can use the same without passing any of the `arm` creds within `provider` block.